# How to store and reuse leaflet LatLngs in Database

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

Currently I save coordinates for an polygon in this format into database:

```
[52.32527, 12.99683],[52.32191, 13.76587],[52.45936, 13.79333],[52.68637, 13.39233],[52.69636, 13.03528]
```

Later I fetch an array of the polygons from database, so I have something like `$polygon_array[$key]['coordinates']` where the latlngs are a string.

With PHP adding a polygon to map works:

```
<script>
 <?php
  $coords = $polygon_array[$key]['coordinates'];
  echo "L.polygon([$coords]).addTo(map);";
 ?>
</script>
```

But adding to map without PHP does not work neither throws an error:

```
<script>
 var polygon_array = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($polygon_array); ?>' ); // transfer PHP Array to Javascript

 jQuery.each(polygon_array, function (index, value) {
  coords = polygon_array[index]['coordinates'];
  L.polygon([coords]).addTo(map);
 });
</script>
```

I think the problem is that Javascript handles the coords as string.

My Questions: How can I use entries from database for a valid latlngs parameter?
Isn't there an easy way to use the format above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably right in assuming that your `coords` variable is still a string.

You should probably just convert it again into an array of latLng coordinates:

```js
var coordsArray = JSON.parse("[" + coords + "]");
L.polygon(coordsArray).addTo(map);
```

Comment: This really works! But I don't know why I have to quote the brackets!?

Comment: You know that `JSON.parse` takes a string as argument, and that strings are represented between quotes in JS and PHP. Here it is like doing `JSON.parse( "[" + "[lat1, lng1], [lat2, lng2], ..." + "]");` because `coords` is still a string. You would have done exactly the same in PHP with `json_decode`. It just seems that your `$coords` variable simply holds the content of your database record, as plain text. That is also why `echo "L.polygon([$coords]).addTo(map);";` does work, since `$coords` is text `echo` is happy with it.